# Using "Text to Columns" macro on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

This image shows the initial state of the columns, in UK format. #value if I try to add 1 to it, False if I run `ISNUMBER()` on it, and True if I use text to column on entry to swap period & comma.  Once in true state, I can use the numbers, but for some this true state isn't reached.  Instead, they result in the error handling convert to number diamond that pops up.

I used the recorder to record the text to columns procedure on a single column.  It produces the following:

```
Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

I have roughly 60 columns this must be applied to and my current solution is to have 60 entries of this block of code with different cell references, which ends up running very slowly.

- Is there a way to apply this to multiple columns?
- Is there some code I can delete out of this block to make it run faster?

I could not find answers while searching.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't fix the manipulations you do so that the end result is a true number? What sort of manipulation is it?

Comment: I have numbers in UK format like 1.000,00.  These are stored as strings and excel is unable to determine the value of them until I change the format to 1,000.00.  I use a block of code, once per column in the same manor as the code I linked above.  This gets me halfway there, but many of the columns are still not set to number after I run the first macro.  The macro in my question cleans up the errors thrown via text to column.

Comment: Selection is not recommended unless you specifically need it and also makes the code run slower. Some sample data could help to provide a more efficient solution

Comment: You can edit your question to add more information

Comment: Ultimately I have a spreadsheet full of UK number format which excel is reading as strings, I must convert all these strings to numbers in US format using a macro or else they do not populate the pivot table in the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though using `selection` is not ideal, there are ways to utilize `Selection` to support more efficient looping of columns to `.texttocolumns`.

Note that I do not have any additional arguments in `texttocolumns`, which may or may not be a problem for you depending on your use.

```
Private Sub TTC()
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        Selection.TextToColumns
    Else
        Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, er As Long, ec As Long, col As Long
        sr = Selection.Row 'start row
        sc = Selection.Column 'start column
        er = Selection.Rows.Count + sr - 1 'end row
        ec = Selection.Columns.Count + sc - 1 'end column
        For col = sc To ec
            Range(Cells(sr, col), Cells(er, col)).TextToColumns
        Next col
    End If
End Sub
```

In the above, the selection is used to define variables, which are then specific ranges to loop through and apply the `texttocolumns`.

Additional note, I have not set this up to skip columns, e.g., would not work for non-contiguous ranges; this will work for contiguous ranges, across multiple rows/columns.

---

In terms of speeding up the process, you can use turn off `screenupdating`, `calculation`, and `displayalerts`, prior to executing.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, I will review this and see if it works for me!