# Text to column Macro glitch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this macro as a shortcut to using the Text To Column prompt. I highlight the column or group of vertical cells in question and when running the macro the message box accepts a one character delimiter. The problem occurs when all three of these things happen.

1. It is the first time I am running the macro in the workbook (If I run the macro again the glitch does not occur)
2. I highlight an entire column
3. There are blank cells above the first cell that needs to be parsed.

For example, if I have the text "123-456" in cell D10, I highlight all of column D and run the macro delimiting by "-" it parses the data into D1 and E1. If I delete the info in row 1 and try it again it works I except parsing the data into D10 and E10

Not sure how to troubleshoot this otherwise.

```
Sub Txt2Clm()
'
' Txt2Clm Macro
'

'

    mbox = InputBox("Text-To-Columns", "Quick Step", "Enter Delimiter")

    Selection.TextToColumns , DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=mbox, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


End Sub
```

Expected results should be how Text to Column typically works.

Comment: How are you calling this macro?  Is it with a shortcut, a context menu, QAB, or other?

Comment: I put an icon into the quick access toolbar. So, I click that button in the quick access toolbar and the message box pops up asking for a delimiter. I enter "-" and hit enter. Then the macro finishes.

Comment: Looks like it's tied to your fieldinfo.  Let me take a stab at an answer that might be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. It includes a lot of error checking and data validation to make sure it can only Text-To-Columns on valid data:

```
Sub Txt2Clm()

    Dim rValues As Range
    Dim rArea As Range
    Dim sDelim As String

    'Evalute selected range for valid data that can have text to columns performed on it (no blanks, no formulas)
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Selection.HasFormula = False And Len(Selection.Value) > 0 Then Set rValues = Selection
    Else
        'Only get constant values from first column (text to columns can only work on a single column at a time)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rValues = Selection.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If Not rValues Is Nothing Then
        'Prompt for delimiter
        sDelim = InputBox("Text-To-Columns", "Quick Step", "Enter Delimiter")
        If Len(sDelim) = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel
        If Len(sDelim) > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Delimiter must be a single character"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'Prevent DisplayAlerts to suppress potential "Override existing data?" prompt
        For Each rArea In rValues.Areas
            rArea.TextToColumns rArea, xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelim
        Next rArea
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        MsgBox "No cells containing valid data selected."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in cutting out a lot of the falses, etc., I have this code which appears to work, not being bound to your `fieldinfo` array:

```
Sub ttc()
    mbox = InputBox("Text-To-Columns", "Quick Step", "Enter Delimiter")
    Selection.TextToColumns , DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=mbox
End Sub
```

---

Tested on some quick data... before :

[image]

and after:

[image]

---

**Edit1:**

Going to take a look at avoiding carrying through with `Selection` in the TTC, similar to the other post I linked in the comments...

Give this a shot to see if specifying the starting/ending row won't resolve that issue:

```
Sub TTC()
    mbox = InputBox("Text-To-Columns", "Quick Step", "Enter Delimiter")
    Dim sr As Long, er As Long, c As Long
    sr = Selection.Row 'start row
    er = Selection.Rows.Count + sr - 1 'end row
    c = Selection.Column 'column
    Range(Cells(sr, c), Cells(er, c)).TextToColumns , DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=mbox
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried implementing your much cleaner code but am still running into issues. It works if the only cell (or set of cells) is being selected, however, if you run the above example highlighting the entire column the issue remains (but only on the first run of the macro as any successive run of the macro will produce a correct result). Hope this makes sense but let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @TrevorWightman I'm having trouble replicating your issue, as this has worked for selecting an entire columns or several cells (just tested).  I will also link you to a post I did the other day which does [TTC to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58397071/3233363) (not ideal for your situation, but good info to have).  Going to need to dig into your error when you try it the first time... are you getting an error?  What exactly is and is not happening on the first run?

Comment: Is there anyway to post a video in the comments (Sorry I am new so please let me know if i am commenting or posting in an incorrect fashion)? I open a new workbook, type "123-456" into cell D10, for example. Highlight column D by clicking on "D". Click the icon i saved in the quick access toolbar that contains the macro. Enter my delimiter of "-" and click ok. The result is 123 in D1 and 456 in E1. If I then clear out row 1 and attempt the same steps above 123 appears in D10 and 456 appears in E10 (this second run is correct placement of the delimited bits and this should happen every time)

Comment: @TrevorWightman I believe people have posted gifs with their posts... you can try that.  I take it there is no error?  Trying to think of what would cause all of the data to move up to the top of a column and i'm at a loss...

Comment: That is correct, no error code, is just moves all non-empty cells up to row 1 of that column, then does the delimit.

Comment: @TrevorWightman Do you have any change events or other code happening for this worksheet?

Comment: I have other macros in my personal workbook but am not activating any of them. I tried your replacement code but it threw up an error when I attempted it.

Comment: @TrevorWightman my fault, I had the incorrect language for `c` the column; just updated post.